# Xpages xp:customValidator: do I need to create a separate bean for each customValidator?

Tags: java, xpages, managed-bean, xpages-ssjs

So far I only had to build a single java customValidator in my applications. In a current project I'm now facing the necessity to have multiple customValidators I need to register with the application.

Since I can only have one `validate` method inside my bean the question arises whether I need to build separate objects for each validation option. Or is there a way to have one common bean containing all the needed validators? But then, what would that look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a managed bean, you can define your own methods for your validation. The method must have three parameters and return *void*:

```
public void validateDemo( FacesContext fc, UIComponent uiCmp, Object toValidate ){
   throw new ValidationException( new FacesMessage("Validation error.") );
}
```

In the XPage you can now use this method in your UIComponent:

```
<xp:inputText
    id="myText"
    validator="#{myBean.validateDemo}" />
```

You can have as many validating methods as you want.

Comment: Thanks, as always :-). Just to get it clear: in this case I'd register this as a managed bean instead of a custom validator in my faces-config? Cause if I do it via a validator I'm asked to implement a method "validate". As far as I understand I can't combine the bean method with the other standard validator available, or can I?